# How to pass a variable from c# into javascript for plotting in plotly.js

Tags: javascript, c#, html, plotly

I am trying to pass X and Y data generated in c# into plotly.js that update every second (or as often as programmatically possible).  How would I reference in javascript a variable like x and y located in the .json file or c#?  Ultimately, the javascript piece should run plotly with x and y taken from the c# code (Or in c#, I can generate a .json file every second).  Plotly allows for dynamic updating, so this should be possible if the variables can be passed.  I have included my starting point below:

**C# Code:**

```
dataPoint.X = 0;
dataPoint.Y = retrieveVariable(MachineInfoService.Instance.machineInfo.plot, 0);
xstr = dataPoint.X.ToString();
ystr = dataPoint.Y.ToString();
for (i = 1; i < numdataPoints; i++)
{
     dataPoint.X = i;
     dataPoint.Y = retrieveVariable(MachineInfoService.Instance.machineInfo.plot, i);
     xstr =xstr +", " +dataPoint.X.ToString();
     ystr = ystr +", "+ dataPoint.Y.ToString();
     Globals.PlotlyX = xstr;
     Globals.PlotlyY = ystr;
     graphData.Add(dataPoint);
}
            
webView.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/index3.html"));
```

**index3.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Plotly.js -->
    <!----<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>  -->

    <script src="plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Assets/xydata.json"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV -->
    <div id="graphDiv"></div>
    <script>

        
        jQuery.get('../Assets/xydata.json');
        Plotly.newPlot('plotly-chart', data, layout);
        
        
        

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**xydata.json:**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "x": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
      "y": [ 0, 3, 6, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 4 ],
      "type": "scatter",
      "name": "Plot 1"
    },
    {
      "x": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
      "y": [ 0, 4, 7, 8, 3, 6, 3, 3, 4 ],
      "type": "scatter",
      "name": "Plot 2"
    },
    {
      "x": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
      "y": [ 0, 5, 3, 10, 5.33, 2.24, 4.4, 5.1, 7.2 ],
      "type": "scatter",
      "name": "Plot 3"
    }
  ],
  "layout": {
    "showlegend": true,
    "legend": { "orientation": "h" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't write to a file for each plot update. The cleanest way would probably be to use [Newtonsoft's Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which helps you convert .NET objects to JSON. If you don't want to use another library, you could also just manually format a String into valid JSON, but that may be much more complicated/error prone.

After having new plot data, call the function via C#, like this:

```
PlotyObject data = new PlotyObject()
webView.Document.InvokeScript("updatePlotWithNewData", {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)})
```

OR

```
webView.Document.InvokeScript("updatePlotWithNewData", {"{...manually formatted JSON...}"})
```

In your `index3.html` file, you could do something like this to accept new data and update the Ploty chart:

```
<script>

    var plotlyData = {...}
    var layout = { ... }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        Plotly.newPlot('plotly-chart', plotlyData, layout);
    });

    function updatePlotWithNewData(newData) {
        plotlyData = JSON.parse(newData);
        Plotly.redraw('plotly-chart');
    }

</script>
```